# Regarding EasyMock for class that contains method with parameters

Tags: java, easymock

I want to know how to write test cases with EasyMock for classes that contain methods with arguments and returns some object. Pls let me know if it is not detailed enough. I did worked on it for hours to solve it..so i opted stackoverflow now.

The following is the method present in Class XYZ that i'm trying to workout

```
public static Identifier getMachineIdentifierFor( Machine machine ) {
    Identifier identifier = new IdentifierImpl();
    identifier.setMachine(machine.getMachine());
    identifier.setMachineIdentifierType(machine.getMachineIdentifierType());
    return identifier;
}
```

The following is how Machine class looks like( just sample ...i skipped getters and setter while copying to here)

```
public class MachineImpl implements Machine {
    private String machine;
    private MachineIdentifierType machineIdentifierType;
    //@followed by some strings and getters and setters for the corresponding fields
}
```

The following is how identifier looks like

```
public class IdentifierImpl implements Identifier {
    private String machine;
    private machineIdentifierType machineIdentifierType; 

    public void setInstrument(String machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public String getMachine() {
        return machine;
    }

    public MachineIdentifierType getMachineIdentifierType() {
        return machineIdentifierType;
    }

    public void setInstrumentIdentifierType(MachineIdentifierType machineIdentifierType) {
        this.machineIdentifierType = machineIdentifierType;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a method like the one you're trying to test, I don't think I would use mocking to test it. I would probably write a test like this:

```
@Test
public void thatMachineIdentifierIsCreatedWithMachineAndType() {
    final String machineString = "machine";
    final MachineIdentifierType machineIdType = new MachineIdentifierType();

    final Machine machine = new Machine();
    machine.setMachine( machineString );
    machine.setMachineIdentifierType( machineIdType );

    final Identifier identifier = XYZ.getMachineIdentifierFor( machine );
    assertThat( identifier.getMachine(), is(machineString));
    assertThat( identifier.getMachineIdentifierType(), is( machineIdType ));
}
```

---

Now, having said I wouldn't use mocks to test this, it is possible to do that.

You have 2 options:

1. Mock the Machine class and check that the returned values are in the Identifier object returned. This is a usal use case for mocking and is quite simple and achievable with EasyMock.
2. Mock the Machine Class and the IdentifierImpl constructor call and check the mock Identifier gets calls to the setters with the results of the getters from the machine mock. This is much more complicated and not possible with just EasyMock, it requires PowerMock too

**Option 1:**

Mock the Machine object passed to the method and set up expectations for the method calls. This uses the standard expect, replay and verify methods form EasyMock. A test would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void thatInteractionWithMachineIsAsExpected() {
    final String machineString = "machine";
    final MachineIdentifierType machineIdType = new MachineIdentifierType();

    final Machine mockedMachined = EasyMock.createMock(Machine.class);
    EasyMock.expect( mockedMachined.getMachine() ).andReturn( machineString );
    EasyMock.expect( mockedMachined.getMachineIdentifierType() ).andReturn( machineIdType );

    EasyMock.replay( mockedMachined );

    final Identifier identifier = XYZ.getMachineIdentifierFor( mockedMachined );
    assertThat( identifier.getMachine(), is(machineString));
    assertThat( identifier.getMachineIdentifierType(), is( machineIdType ));

    EasyMock.verify( mockedMachined );
}
```

**Option 2:**

This is much more complicated and convoluted. I'm not really what this approach gives you over the other two approaches I've already mentioned, but I'm including it as a knowledge sharing exercise as much as anything else.

The main issue for using mocking to test your method is that you instantiate an object that you might want to mock. Instantiation is the killer for most mocking frameworks, but it can be handled with PowerMock. It cannot be done with EasyMock, it is outside the scope of what that library was designed to do.

PowerMock is able to mock the calls to constructors for specified classes. It can also do some other fantastic things, but I'll leave those to you to find out, [(documentation here)](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/). In your case, it could be used to make the call to the `IdentifierImpl` constructor return a mock object that you could then set your expectations on.

You could then also mock the `Machine` object that is provided to the method and set the expectations for that.

It's a bit gnarly (hence why I wouldn't use this technique for this type of test) but here is a test using both PowerMock and EasyMock to test your method.

```
@Test
public void thatInteractionWithMachineAndIdentifierIsAsExpected() throws Exception {
    final String machineString = "machine";
    final MachineIdentifierType machineIdType = new MachineIdentifierType();

    final Machine mockedMachined = EasyMock.createMock(Machine.class);
    EasyMock.expect( mockedMachined.getMachine() ).andReturn( machineString );
    EasyMock.expect( mockedMachined.getMachineIdentifierType() ).andReturn( machineIdType );

    final IdentifierImpl mockedIdentifierImpl = EasyMock.createMock(IdentifierImpl.class);
    mockedIdentifierImpl.setMachine(machineString);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    mockedIdentifierImpl.setMachineIdentifierType( machineIdType );
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();

    PowerMock.expectNew(IdentifierImpl.class).andReturn( mockedIdentifierImpl );

    PowerMock.replayAll();

    final IdentifierImpl identifier = (IdentifierImpl) XYZ.getMachineIdentifierFor( mockedMachined );
    assertThat( identifier, is( mockedIdentifierImpl ) );

    PowerMock.verifyAll();
}
```